# Ceating COM object with teeChart control

Tags: .net, visual-c++, teechart

I'm creating a COM Component that should draw chart using teechart for .net.

in my vc++ project i have to create a window component with teeChart control, and i have problems with creating teeChart control.

I've made an instance of teeChart using IChartPtr and CreateInstance method, but i'd like to get acces to its properties, like, size of a control, position, etc, in other words, everything that automaticaly sets in form designer in c#.

what methods of an interface should i use?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=14091#p62065).